How to search future events in Evolution calendar
I use Evolution 3.42.4 under OpenSUSE Leap 15.5 on x86 hardware.
I want to do an advanced search for calendar events of a particular type in the future. According to my notes from previous searches, selecting "Active Appointments" used to show only future events, but this does not seem to work any more: it shows all past events matching my search conditions as well.
Is there any way of specifying a date range in an Evolution advanced search? I can't see anything. An "Expression" condition might help, but I can't find any documentation for this.
